# how to get a specific element in json object using bufferReader in java

Tags: java, json

I have JSON`` data I'm getting with java `GET` request.

I need to count how many `age` objects are greater than 50 in the JSON object.

Right now I am just getting the whole JSON data line by line using `bufferreader`, but how do I get the single element `age` in the JSON object and compare it with the number 50?

```java
package problem;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;
    public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
     BufferedReader rd;
     OutputStreamWriter wr;

    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/age-counting");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.flush();

        // Get the response
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

      }
```

Sample response for JSON data, I need to get the `age` value as an `integer`:

```
{
   "data":
     "key=IAfpK,
      age=58,
      key=WNVdi,
      age=64,
      key=jp9zt,
      age=47"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need a json library like jackson

```
  ObjectMapper mapper =new ObjectMapper();
  try{

   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
     new FileReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())));

   //convert the json string back to object
   Data cdataObj = mapper.readValue(br, Data.class);
   if (cdataObj.age>50) {
```

you'd have to map the json to a class or use more rudimentary json api reading nodes

for reference 
https://java2blog.com/jackson-example-read-and-write-json/

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of the most popular JSON libraries such as `Jackson` or `Gson` to parse value of the key `data`, then you can narrow down the problem to **How to count how many ages whose value is grater than 50 in the value string?**.

**Code snippet**

```
String valueStr = "key=IAfpK,age=58,key=WNVdi,age=64,key=jp9zt,age=47";
int count = 0;
for (String part : valueStr.split(",")) {
    String[] subparts = part.split("=", 2);
    if ("age".equals(subparts[0]) && Integer.valueOf(subparts[1]) > 50) {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.print(count);
```

**Console output**

> 2

Answer (score 0):

Without any JSON libraries, please try following code

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/age-counting");
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

```
        //Console.WriteLine("Content length is {0}", response.ContentLength);
        //Console.WriteLine("Content type is {0}", response.ContentType);

        // Get the stream associated with the response.
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format.
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string _data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
        var numbers = _data.Split(',');

        var age = numbers.Where(c => c.Contains("age="));
        int _total = 0; 
        foreach (var item in age)
        {
           string _item = item.Replace("\"}", "");
            if (int.Parse(_item.Replace("age=", "")) >= 50){
                _total++;
            }
        }
        //Console.WriteLine(readStream.ReadToEnd());

        Console.WriteLine(_total);
        response.Close();
        readStream.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

//final output will be 128